# I cannot get nested JSON-results through AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have tried to follow multiple guides on how to do this - but none is working. I have also tried to add a `$.each`-function inside the existing one, without success. This is what my JSON result looks like (it's just a snippet, might be broken when directly copied here, but you get the point):

```
 {
      "loc": [
        {
          "path_id": "Trail1",
          "places": [
            {
              "way_distance": 2,
              "trace_location": {
                "lat": 51.2383342365623,
                "lng": 20.265387296676636
              },
              "trace_info": "",
              "way_name": ""
            }
          ]

        }
       ]
    }
```

I am able to get data from "path_id", but not from "trace_location", with this code:

```
    $.getJSON(url, function(data){
        $.each(data.loc,function(i,emp){
                var a = this.path_id;
                console.log(a); //works

                var b = this.places[0].trace_location;
                var c = this.places.trace_location;
                console.log(b); //seems to output objects, but then crashes
                console.log(c); //output is undefined

       });
});
```

When I do a console.log(b);, the system responds with the following error:

```
tringhar.html:36 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trace_location' of undefined
```

I  want to be able to output the data from "trace_location" without it being `undefined` or with errors. Thank you.

Edit:

Still not working with this code:

```
    var url = 'https://forward-byte-711.appspot.com/read/Test/Development/en';

$(function(){

            $.getJSON(url, function(data){

              $.each(data.paths,function(i,emp){          
                var b = this.places[0].place_position;

                console.log(b);
                });



            });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

`places` is an array.

```
var c = this.places.trace_location;
```

needs to be

```
var c = this.places[0].trace_location;
```

[Here's a CodePen with the example](http://codepen.io/emiloberg/pen/yOvvZX?editors=0011) - it's working

The reason it's crashing in your example is not because of the `console.log(b)` statement, it's because you try to access `trace_location` from undefined. Remove the `var c` and `console.log(c)` statement from your code.

Comment: I did that on "var b" as an example but it is not working. Neither "var b" or "var c" is working in the code snippet.

Comment: Updated with a CodePen

Comment: I edited my post - even with the exact copy of your code snippet, I recieve the error message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trace_location' of undefined

Comment: Take a look at the JSON. See that only the first two of the items in the array has `places` set? That means, that `this.places[0]` can be undefined and you've to check if it actually exists before trying to access it. E.g. do `if (this.places.length) { console.log(this.places[0].place_position); }`. I've updated the CodePen with the safeguard.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cyvLae9u/) with it working. There's either something else wrong with the rest of the json or one of your objects doesn't actually have the property you're trying to access in the json feed. For example a `place` doesn't have a `trace_location` in the json.

```
var data = {
  "loc": [{
    "path_id": "Trail1",
    "places": [{
      "way_distance": 2,
      "trace_location": {
        "lat": 51.2383342365623,
        "lng": 20.265387296676636
      },
      "trace_info": "",
      "way_name": ""
    }]
  }]
};

data.loc.forEach(function(item) {
  console.log(item);
  item.places.forEach(function(place){
    console.log(place);
  });
});
```